# Regex error message doesn't work

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using mvc asp.net mvc4 app.
I validate one entity with a regex.

When I put wrong data (when the regex is blocking the action), there is no error message, but the field that is validates is highlighted.

Otherwise, If I put valid data (the regex doesn't block the action) , the data is saved, so it works fine.

Question : why there is no error message?

In my entities :

```
[RegularExpression("(^1000[0-9]{6}$)", ErrorMessage = "Please enter a valid Account Number")]
```

In the cshtml :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
...
```

In my final html result file :

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
...
<input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Account Number must be a number." data-val-regex="Please enter a valid Account Number" data-val-regex-pattern="(^1000[0-9]{6}$)" data-val-required="The Account Number field is required." id="AccountId" name="AccountId" type="number" value="" />
```

Thanks to help me, I don't understand why it isn't working :-/
Do I have to put a "warning" div in html? It seems that no but...

Comment: What is a valid AccountId ? You don't have to place a warning `div` inside the `html`.

Does other errors appear ? like if you leave it empty ?

Comment: @Ofiris : between 1000000000 -> 1000999999, so the regex isn't the problem, it workd fine, but there is no error message if the regex block the action!

Comment: Ok, see my edited comment

Comment: @Ofiris : the same as if I put wrong data ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just forget to put the `@Html.ValidationSummary()` in the `.cshtml` file.
There is an other way to show errors by using `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Contact)` for instance for the fiels 'contact'.

Sorry for the forget, thanks for your attention and I hope this help someone